# Why does Ubuntu offer an old version of GNS3 instead of the latest one?

Tags: apt

I notice that GNS3 v0.8.7-2 was installed on Ubuntu via `sudo apt install gns3` instead of the new version which is [GNS3 v2.1.20](https://www.gns3.com/software/download) as this question is asked.

May I know why Ubuntu still using the old version of GNS3 in it's repository?

```
user@linux:~$ sudo apt show gns3
Package: gns3
Version: 0.8.7-2
Priority: optional
Section: multiverse/net
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Daniel Lintott <daniel@serverb.co.uk>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 22.7 MB
Depends: ucf, python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~), dynamips (>= 0.2.8), python-qt4 (>= 4.5), xdotool, xterm
Recommends: wireshark
Homepage: http://www.gns3.net/
Download-Size: 3,219 kB
APT-Sources: http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
Description: Graphical Network Simulator
 GNS3 is a graphical network simulator that allows simulation of
 complex networks and to launch simulations on them. It is an excellent
 complementary tool to real labs for administrators of Cisco networks
 or people wanting to pass their CCNA, CCNP, CCIP or CCIE certifications.
 It can also be used to experiment with features of Cisco IOS or to check
 configurations that need to be deployed later on real routers.
 .
 You may configure devices ranging from Cisco routers, Cisco PIX firewalls,
 Cisco ASA Firewalls, Cisco IDS to JunOS routers using Qemu or Pemu. GNS3
 uses dynamips as an emulation back end, an IOS emulator which allows users
 to run IOS binary images from Cisco Systems.
 .
 Cisco IOS, PIX, ASA or JunOS software images are not included.

user@linux:~$
```

I know I can get the latest version by updating the repo and install it as follows.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gns3-gui
```

I just want to know why Ubuntu didn't use the latest version of GNS3 by default?

Comment: The suggested link explains why. By the way, there's no need for `sudo` if you want to run `apt show`. Also note that if you install a ppa and you run into issues, the recommended way to go back is to use `ppa-purge`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed

Comment: Also, looking at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gns3 will show you that even 19.04 has the same version as 18.04. It's too early to say what will be in 19.10 (because initially even the development version uses many packages from its predecessor). If you want to know more about 19.10, look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseSchedule and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2417100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Ubuntu software, including GNS3, is imported from Debian. Debian gets the code from volunteers who package the software for everybody's benefit.

According to [Debian Bug #784871](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784871) and [Debian PTS](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gns3), no current community member cares enough about GNS3 to upload the newer version to Debian.

Anybody who wishes to do so can solve this problem. Simply volunteer at http://mentors.debian.net to learn how to package software and become a new maintainer.